# Why mouseover and moveout don't work for all classes which have the same name?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to apply classList.add during the mouseover and classList.remove during the mouseout. The class which should be added or removed is ".portraitBG". It has a #32353F for the background.

I don't know why this isn't working when I tell the code to apply this function to all my html class ".portrait.flex". I don't want to use jQuery at this moment.

See the whole code on https://codepen.io/gabrielacaesar/pen/Pmrpzm

My Javascript:

```
var portrait = document.querySelectorAll(".portrait.flex")

  portrait.addEventListener("mouseover", function() {
    portrait.classList.add("portraitBG");
  });

  portrait.addEventListener("mouseout", function() {
    portrait.classList.remove("portraitBG");
  });
```

My HTML:

```
<section class="container">
        <div class="portraits flex">
            <a class="portrait flex one" href="#" alt="Foto:">
                <img src="http://cbn.globoradio.globo.com/estaticos/fotos/uploads2015/categorias/moreno-no-radio/11239_header.png">
                <div class="portraitContent">
                    <p class="portraitName">
                        Eliseu Padilha
                    </p>
                    <p class="portraitGovernment">
                        governo Michel Temer
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a class="portrait flex two" href="#">
                <img src="http://cbn.globoradio.globo.com/estaticos/fotos/uploads2015/categorias/moreno-no-radio/11239_header.png">
                <div class="portraitContent">
                    <p class="portraitName">
                        Eva Chiavon
                    </p>
                    <p class="portraitGovernment">
                        governo Dilma Rousseff
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>

            <a class="portrait flex three" href="#">
                <img src="http://cbn.globoradio.globo.com/estaticos/fotos/uploads2015/categorias/moreno-no-radio/11239_header.png">
                <div class="portraitContent">
                    <p class="portraitName">
                        Jaques Wagner
                    </p>
                    <p class="portraitGovernment">
                        governo Dilma Rousseff
                    </p>
                </div>
            </a>
     </section>
```

My CSS:

```
            a {
                text-decoration: none;
                cursor: pointer;
            }

            .container {
                padding: 0;
                max-width: 1500px;
                margin: 0 auto;
            }


            .flex {
                display: flex;
            }

            .portraits {
                flex-direction: row;
                flex-wrap: wrap;
                justify-content: space-between;
                padding: 30px 80px;
            }

            .portrait {
                max-width: 800px;
                max-height: 340px;
                flex-direction: column;
                text-align: center;
                padding-top: 30px;
            }

            .portraitBG {
                background: #32353F;
                border-radius: 5%;
            }

            .portrait img {
                max-width: 800px;
                max-height: 200px;
            }

            .portraitContent {
                border: 3px #32353F solid;
                border-radius: 5%;
                background: #00EC85;
            }

            .portraitName {
                font-size: 200%;
                color: white;
                padding-top: 7px;
            }

            .portraitGovernment {
                font-size: 100%;
                color: #32353F;
                padding-bottom: 7px;
            }
```

Comment: ahh, now the problem is obvious ... `portrait` is a LIST of elements, you can't add an event listener to a list of elements, and if you used the **developer** tools console, you would've seen the problem

Comment: I did try to find out the solution with developer tools console. Since I couldn't find a way after a few hours, I decided to look for some help on Stackoverflow. I'm new as developer, so I would be grad if you could help me. Best regards

Comment: are you trying to add background during mouseover and removed the background when mouseout?

Comment: exactly, @PenAndPapers.

Comment: OMG @PenAndPapers - it took your comment for me to realise how ridiculous my answer and comments were!!! :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

better to do it in CSS

```
.portrait:hover{
  background: #32353F;
    border-radius: 5%;
}
```